# Writing Unit Test with Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: unit-testing, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm facing Difficulty writing unit tests with Spring Data Neo4j.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { Application.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SomeRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository someRepository;

    @Autowired
    Session session;

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        System.out.println(someRepository.findAll());
    }

}
```

I have no idea how to populate data into database.

For Unit Testing, I've set property of driver to `driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver`
@ ogm.properties, in order to start Embedded Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate data using `session.query()` where you supply a Cypher statement to set up data. Or, if you want a handle to the embedded graph database, this snippet of code will help:

```
EmbeddedDriver embeddedDriver = (EmbeddedDriver) Components.driver();
GraphDatabaseService databaseService = embeddedDriver.getGraphDatabaseService();
```